# jBPM Business Central - Error calling container CheckPeriod_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Error unmarshalling input

Tags: jbpm, rule-engine, kie, dmn, businesscentral

Getting the following error while sending the request through Postman using content-type JSON.

{
"type" : "FAILURE",
"msg" : "Error calling container CheckPeriod_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Error unmarshalling input",
"result" : null
}

```
{
"lookup": "Period-Session",
"commands": [
    {
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "periods": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "2023-08-01",
                        "endDate": "2023-07-31"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "return-object": false
        }
    },
    {
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "errorMessage": {
                    "Message": ""
                }
            },
            "return-object": true,
            "out-identifier": "errorMessages"
        }
    },
    {
        "fire-all-rules": {
            "max": 100
        }
    },
    {
        "get-objects": {
            "out-identifier": "errorMessages"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Modified the code as follows. But still getting the same error.

```
{
"lookup": "Period-Session",
"commands": [
    {
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "periods": [
                    {
                        "period": {
                            "startDate": "2023-08-01",
                            "endDate": "2023-07-31"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "return-object": false
        }
    },
    {
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "errorMessage": {
                    "Message": ""
                }
            },
            "return-object": true
        }
    },
    {
        "fire-all-rules": {
            "max": 100,
            "out-identifier": "errorMessage"
        }
    },
    {
        "get-objects": {
            "out-identifier": "errorMessage"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Created data objects periods, period and errorMessage. Using these data objects in the DMN file. There is no error in the DMN. Build and Deployment are also fine. No errors or warning.

[image: Validate Period - Literal expression]

[image: Validate Period - Data type declaration]

[image: errorMessage - Data Object][image: Periods - Data object] [image: Period - Data Object]